# Have an Image take up the fullscreen and then shrink down to fit where I place it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a school project, I have a website that I have an image that I'm using as a banner below my nav bar, I want to have the Image take up the whole screen when the site loads and then shrink down to where I have it placed on my website, could someone point me in the right direction of where I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the scale and animation function in CSS.  Look what I did here:

```css
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freewebheaders.com%2Fwp-content%2Fgallery%2Fcats%2Fcats-header-20738-800x200.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=8329f05fb294bfb7965b0ee934c2180159e991175ced2d23020b362fe320f4b9&ipo=images);
  scale: 5;
  animation: scale 2000ms ease-in-out forwards;
}


@keyframes scale {
  to {
    transform: scale(0.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
some nav bar stuff
</div>

<div id="banner">
</div>
```